# Ways to reverse print a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a program that would convert an int to binaries. So far I have it print out the remainders, but it has to be printed in reverse for it to be a proper binary. I am not allowed to use any methods.

Here's my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter A Postive Number:");

        int i = sc.nextInt();
        int j = i; //backup
        int k = 0; //remainder

        while (j != 0) {
            k = j % 2;
            j /= 2;

            String reversedStr = "";

            switch (k) {
                case 0:
                    reversedStr += "0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    reversedStr += "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    reversedStr += "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    reversedStr += "3";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    reversedStr += "4";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    reversedStr += "5";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    reversedStr += "6";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    reversedStr += "7";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    reversedStr += "8";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    reversedStr += "9";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    reversedStr += "A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    reversedStr += "B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    reversedStr += "C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    reversedStr += "D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    reversedStr += "E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    reversedStr += "F";
                    break;
            }

            for (int l = reversedStr.length() - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
                reversedStr.charAt(i);
                System.out.print(reversedStr.charAt(l));

            }

        }
        System.out.println("done"); 
    }
}
```

this code gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 178
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at radixHandmade.Handmade.main(Handmade.java:73)
```

The for loop at the bottom is the reversing part, but im not sure how to use charAt to complete the code. To be honest im very confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sure looks like you're trying to handle hexadecimal values.  What base is the input?

Comment: What do you think `reversedStr.charAt(i);` does? I mean, other than causing the SIOOBE, what do you intend it to do?

Comment: @user6690200 how can it be greater than 1?

Comment: @AndyTurner impossible, I believe that is rundandent.

Comment: Wouldn't a lookup table work better then that aweful switch/case??? I.e. `char lookup_table[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};`  Then you could just do `reversedStr += lookup_table[k];` ???

Answer (score 1):

This statement causes the problem:

```
reversedStr.charAt(i);
```

Aside from causing an exception (because you're trying to get the (originally entered value)-th character in the string, which is by outside the bounds of the string, unless that value happens to be 0), it has no other side effect.

Just remove this line.

Comment: Removing that line will make the program compile, but it does not give correct output.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

removing the line `reversedStr.charAt(i)` will resolve the issue, but the program will still not convert to binary correctly.  Your string still needs to be reversed.  Might I suggest using the `StringBuilder` class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.println("Enter A Postive Number:");

        int i = sc.nextInt();
        int r = 0;
        int b = 2; // now you can just change this for what base (binary, hex, ...)

        while (i != 0) {
            r = i % b;
            i /= b;

            switch (r) {
                case 0:
                    out.append("0");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    out.append("1");
                    break;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(out.reverse());
    }
}
```

Your code would work fine if you move the reversing for loop out of the while loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String revStr = "";

    System.out.println("Enter A Postive Number:");

    int i = sc.nextInt();
    int r = 0;
    int b = 2; // now you can just change this for what base (binary, hex, ...)

    while (i != 0) {
        r = i % b;
        i /= b;

        switch (r) {
            case 0:
                revStr += "0";
                break;
            case 1:
                revStr += "1";
                break;
            // ... for hex
        }
    } 
    for (int j = revStr.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(revStr.charAt(j));
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

But what I really don't understand is why you even have to reverse the string if you can just do:

```
reversedStr = "0" + reversedStr;  // of course it will no longer be reversed
// ... for all the cases
```

Even better if you stick with just binary, you could skip the whole switch and do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "";
    System.out.println("Enter A Postive Number:");
    for(int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); i != 0; i /= 2) 
        str = String.valueOf(i % 2) + str;
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Reverse {
   public static void main(String[] args){
    userInput();
  }

   public static void userInput(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String reverseString = console.nextLine(); //This is the word to be written backwards.

 int s = reverseString.length()-1; //length of the word.

   for (int i = s ; i>=0; i--){
   System.out.print(reverseString.charAt(i));
   }
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.